# Remove active class from current div when clicking siblings in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to remove the `active` class from the current div when any of the sibling divs are clicked. For some reason that's not working in my case.

### Below is my HTML and JS

(Notice the section question is selected, and is active).

```
<div class="question">
    <div class="views-field views-field-title views-accordion-header ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-9" aria-controls="ui-id-10" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
            <a href="#q_as-page-4">        
                <span class="field-content">Ex Valde </span>  
            </a>
    </div>  
    <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-id-10" aria-labelledby="ui-id-9" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; height: 643.801979064941px;">
        <div class="views-field views-field-body">        
            <div class="field-content">Blandit immitto iusto natu praesent turpis. Dolore duis ideo meus nimis venio vulpes. At autem commodo dignissim interdico mos vel. Eros letalis nobis quia secundum. Decet metuo neque. Causa incassum lobortis pecus quadrum qui tamen.</div>  
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>


<div class="question active">

  <div class="views-field views-field-title views-accordion-header ui-accordion-header ui-state-active ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-11" aria-controls="ui-id-12" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
        <a href="#q_as-page-5">        
            <span class="field-content">Cogo Ibidem Persto Zelus </span>  
        </a>
  </div>  
  <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-id-12" aria-labelledby="ui-id-11" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; height: 643.801979064941px;">
    <div class="views-field views-field-body">        
        <div class="field-content">Eu hendrerit pala ulciscor. Exputo gilvus tincidunt. Exputo nutus obruo paulatim secundum tation torqueo. Defui esse ille iriure lucidus mauris roto.
        </div>  
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>


<div class="question">

  <div class="views-field views-field-title views-accordion-header ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-13" aria-controls="ui-id-14" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
        <a href="#q_as-page-6">        
            <span class="field-content">Cogo Ibidem Persto Zelus </span>  
        </a>
  </div>  
  <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-id-14" aria-labelledby="ui-id-13" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; height: 643.801979064941px;">
    <div class="views-field views-field-body">        
        <div class="field-content">Eu hendrerit pala ulciscor. Exputo gilvus tincidunt. Exputo nutus obruo paulatim secundum tation torqueo. Defui esse ille iriure lucidus mauris roto.
        </div>  
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

### JS

```
$('.question .ui-state-default a').on("click", function(e) {

    //$(this).parent().parent().closest('div[class=active]').removeClass("active");;
    //$(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $('.question .ui-state-default a').on("click", function(e) {
      $(".question").removeClass("active");
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass("active");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

find the closest `.question` up the tree, add the `.active` class, then find its siblings that has a `.question` and an `.active` class, and remove the `.active`

```
$('.question .ui-state-default a').on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.question').addClass('active').siblings('.question.active').removeClass('active')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".question").removeClass("active");
$(this).parent().parent().addClass("active");
```

This removes `active` from all siblings first, regardless of whether they already have the class.

Comment: Thanks. This was something I was trying to do.